# How to slide down button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have submit button in my application. When user clicked submit button. I want slide down submit button in jQuery or CSS. Can anybody suggest how to do?

Thanks

Comment: Hi please add the relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far and indicate why/where you are stuck thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a class to the button element whenever the user clicks on it by using on of the following methods:

**JQUERY**

```js
$("button").on("click", () => {
  $("button").addClass("clicked");
})
```

```css
button {
transition: transform 300ms ease
}

.clicked {
  transform: translateY(200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Submit</button>
```

**Without Jquery**

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  button.classList.add("clicked")
})
```

```css
button {
  transition: transform 300ms ease
}

.clicked {
  transform: translateY(200px)
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".button").click(function(e){
    $(this).slideDown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">button</button>
```